# StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync - System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: c#, файлы, windows-8

Следующий код при выполнении вызывает исключение типа `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` в строке, помеченной комментарием.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
 var f = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\music\\lpa.mp3"); //"System.UnauthorizedAccessException" : Отказано в доступе.
 mediaplayer.SetSource((await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read)), "mp3");
 mediaplayer.Volume = 1;
}
```

Файл C:\Users\user\Desktop\music\lpa.mp3 существует, текущий пользователь имеет права на чтение файла.

Как побороть это и получить `StorageFile` указанного файла?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На платформах наподобие Windows 8 вы [не можете](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh967755.aspx) получить данные из произвольного места просто так. Каждое приложение находится в «песочнице» — иначе любая загруженная из аппстора игрушка могла бы прочитать все данные данного пользователя.

По умолчанию, программа имеет доступ каталогу, где она инсталлирована, к app data — специальному месту, где приложение может хранить свои данные и настройки (2 шт.: локальный и перемещаемый), и временному каталогу.

Также, программа может получить доступ к файлу а каталоге загрузок или на сменном носителе через `FileOpenPicker` или `FolderPicker` — если пользователь выберет для вас этот файл.

Вы можете также получить доступ к [другим местам](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.knownfolders.aspx) (Documents, Music, Pictures, ...), но для этого вам придётся отконфигурировать манифест.

Вот ещё статья по теме: [*Windows 8: The right way to Read & Write Files in WinRT*](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/windows-8-how-to-read-files-in-winrt.html).

---

Если ваш файл — музыка, она должна находиться в [KnownFolders.MusicLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.knownfolders.musiclibrary.aspx), пропишите желаемый доступ в манифесте, и открывайте через `FileOpenPicker`.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать для файла:

```
File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Запускать приложение от имени администратора.